# Об ударении в слове "жалюзи"

Tags: фонетика

Все-таки, как правильно ставить ударение в слове "жалюзи"? А то слышу все возможные варианты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Только жалюзИ (не жАлюзи). Слово неизменяемое. Запомнить просто: слово французское. А во французском языке ударение неподвижное, всегда на последний слог падает. Так что жалюзИ.

Comment: Тоже так запомнил.

Answer (score 2):

Прожила 16 лет на Камчатке и ни разу не слышала *лОсось*. Да, говорят *лососЕвая икра*, но не *лОсось*.

Comment: **olga-khmelenko**, а в этом слове "лососЕвая" на Камчатке говорят Е или Ё ?

И к слову, как вообще правильно это слово говорить? В словарях видел "лососёвый". По ТВ вроде бы как-то слышал "семейство лосОсевых", через Е, а не Ё.

Или отдельным вопросом вынести? А то тема всё-таки о "жалюзи".

Comment: Если лОсось, то икра получилаь бы лОсосевая. 
Лососёвая и (напрвильное) лосОсевая прождены вариантом лосОсь. Все остальное - ошибка. 
Вот насчет самого факта произношения лОсось на Камчатке ничем не могу подтвердить. Но я ориентируюсь на свидетельства не столь древних авторов, чтобы поверить в полное исчезновение произношения лОсось. Разумеется это не значит, что каждый обязан его слышать лично.

Comment: На Сахалине и в Приморье тоже лосОсь и икра лососЕвая, как и на Камчатке. О лОсосе не слышали.

Comment: Вы прямо сейчас у них консультировались? Именно у рыбаков?  
Понимаете, я всегда с большим пиитетом отношусь к подобного рода свидетельствам, но тут что-то не так. Я ведь насчет этого лОсося не первый год общаюсь - никогда не было прямых возражений по самому тезису, что так говорили и кое-где продолжают говорить. да и в интернете полно свидетельств на эту тему. Дыма без огня не бывает. То ли всё так резко забылось (что вряд ли), то ли действительно мой склероз меня опять попутал. Случается, но чтоб так...

В "икру лососЕвую" верится совсем уж с трудом. Лососёвая, наверно.

Comment: у ВОЕННЫХ МОРЯКОВ ПРИНЯТО ГОВОРИТЬ  подать рапОрт,МурмАнск

Comment: [Это мы знаем][1]


[1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/2617/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: ЛососЁвая, конечно. Просто писала с телефона. там Ё нет. Я не консультировалась с рыбаками, я среди них жила на Сахалине, живу и в Приморье. Но в принципе могу и позвонить боцману знакомому,какие у них варианты бывают.

Comment: Ясно. Но получилась двусмысленность. Тем более, что Nikolja ещё раньше переспрашивал.

Answer (score 2):

жалюзИ. Запомнить можно с помощью рифмы "Замахнулся вдруг лопатой мест питейных завсегдАтай, И сказал мне: «Разгрузи побыстрее жалюзИ!» Способы запоминания ударений в блоге "[Культура речи](http://govorprav.livejournal.com/)"

Answer (score 0):

Жалюз**и**, конечно. Но рискну предположить, что в относительно недалёком будущем под воздействием массового произношения ударение таки сместится. Как например, это произошло в словах фОльга, лОсось, симметрИя и проч.

Answer (score 0):

Да,действительно. Особенно лОсось. Не хотелось бы смещений.

Comment: Смещений куда? Как я понимаю, смещение "лОсось" -> "лосОсь" уже произошло.

Comment: Ну пока еще не окончательно.
Здесь я не согласен срядом авторов, утверждающих, что лОсось никто не произносит. Такой вариант распространён, насколько я знаю, у рыбаков на дальнем Востоке и Камчатке. И ещё, вроде бы, на Севере, только не в Поморье, а восточнее.

Answer (score 0):

был　в　школе　тест　по　６классу、я　некогда　не　слышала、чтобы　ударение　жАлюзи！！

Comment: Хорошо бы как-то поподробнее...

Answer (score -2):

Застрелите меня кто-нибудь!.. По 16-20 лет они прожили, да еще боцманы знакомые... А как насчет 40 с лишним только собственного стажа + отец рожденный на Камчатке моей бабкой, которая к тому времени прожила там уже не менее 12-ти? Лет с 7-ти пришлось ему кочевать вслед за родителями по Курильским островам, Сахалину и Магаданской области. К 15-ти добрался до Приморского края...

НИКОГДА лОсось, только лосОсь!

К тому же, среди боцманов на тихоокеанском флоте всегда хватало выходцев из сухопутной средней полосы, украинских степей и Челябинской области, знавших слово "дОбыча". Насчет Поморья не скажу, но от знакомых питерцев и архангелогородцев также никогда не слыхивала о загадочной рыбе лОсосе. Что-то подсказывает, - она из того же магАзина родом, что и камбалА. В нем еще на окнах жАлюзи висели и процветало совдеповское мЫшление.